# Is it possible to compare each record in a table with the average values of other records in a query

Tags: mysql, sql

For a table in MySQL I have two columns

```
col1   col2
  1     4.5
  1     4.8
  1     4.4
  1     3.9
  1     7.6
  1     4.5
  2     2.9
  2     4.8
  2     5.6
  2     4.5
  3     8.9
  3     9.7
  3     7.8
  3     8.2
  3     4.3
```

what I want to do is

1. calculate the average values of col2 for different values of col1 and this is easy

SELECT col1,AVG(col2) FROM mytable GROUP BY col1

```
1   4.95
2   4.45
3   7.78
```

2. select the record if its col2 value is less than average of col2 values where col1 is equal to col1-1. I couldn't figure out this part:

```
 SELECT col1,col2 FROM mytable WHERE col2<AVG(col2 where col1= current col1-1)
```

The result set should be:

```
2   2.9
2   4.8
2   4.5
3   4.3
```

Since there is no records where col1=0, there will be no record for col1=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having clause and self-join allows you to do this

```
Select a.col1, a.col2, 
   Avg(b.Col2) AvgCol2
From yourTable a
   Join yourTable b 
       On b.col1 = a.col1 - 1     
Group By a.col1, a.col2
Having a.col2 < Avg(b.Col2)
```

For your sample data, for e.g., it returns

```
col1     col2     AvgCol2
-------- -------- --------
2        2.9      4.95
3        4.3      4.45
2        4.5      4.95
2        4.8      4.95
```

Explanation:
  One way to think about this is that `Having` is clause for filtering the result set constructed AFTER Aggregation in a Group By query, whereas `Where` clause is filter for temporary resultset constructed just BEFORE Aggregation, (or before Sorting in a non Group By Query).

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM @yourtable AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT col1, AVG(col2) col2avg
   FROM @yourtable
   GROUP BY col1
) AS t2  ON t1.col1 - 1 = t2.col1
        AND t1.col2 < t2.col2avg;
```

Comment: You and JW together rule planet Sql

Comment: is sqlfiddle out of service ?

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud, but the above code gives                              '1', '4.4'
'1', '3.9'
'2', '2.9'
'2', '4.8'
'2', '5.6'
'2', '4.5'

Comment: Hey Mahmoud, the demo works great, I said it is not working because the code in your answer is missing "AND t1.col2 < t2.col2avg" at the end which is in your demo. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The question matched what I was looking for but not the approach. I thought I would share for others looking for a different solution.

Try the OVER Partition Method.

```
avg(OrderValue) OVER(PARTITION BY industry)
```

https://learnsql.com/blog/over-clause-mysql/